# Flutter Timer function for web?

Tags: flutter

I am searching a timer function that works for the mobile and web like this timer from dart:async:

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer(Duration(seconds: 2),() {});
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using that?

Comment: @Abion47 it doesnt work in flutter for web

Comment: Are you sure? There's no reason that it shouldn't.

Comment: when i try to run my app in the web it tells me that only imports of the type asset or package are allowed

Comment: What's the actual code that causes that error?

Comment: so the exact error is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ik88_o-34T6jwKnldq6V11dGIxFV_9GA/view?usp=sharing